# Sed remove white spaces between words and semicolon

Tags: regex, sed

In a directory, I have several files with notations like these:

```
myKey :
mySecondKey :
blabla :
```

I would like to remove the white spaces before the semicolon, so that they become:

```
myKey:
mySecondKey:
blabla:
```

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/([a-z]*) :/\1:/g' .
```

But I'm getting:

```
": \1 not defined in the RE
```

I also tried:

```
sed -e 's/([a-z]*)\ \:/\1\:/g'
```

The error doesn't change however.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

How is the regex incorrect?

Am I not defining a variable correctly?

Comment: Group parentheses needs to be escaped if not using the extended regex option `-r`, change `'s/([a-z]*) :/\1:/g'` to `'s/\([a-z]*\) :/\1:/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
sed -e 's/ :/:/g'
```

Use the insensitive case:

```
sed -e 's/([a-z]*) :/\1:/ig'
```

or

```
sed -e 's/([a-zA-Z]*) :/\1:/g'
```

Comment: That's a good point but the file is quite long and I'm afraid to ruin other components.

Answer (score 1):

You have lower and UPPER case characters, so you need to define your character class as:

```
sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z]+)\ :/\1:/g'
#               -^-
```

Additionally use anchors (here the `^`) which yields for the given examples:

```
myKey:
mySecondKey:
blabla:
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can remove the white spaces by finding all spaces (`\s*`) between the word (e.g. "myKey") and `:` and replace it with `:`

```
sed -i 's/\s*:/:/g' .
```